# VerneMQ MySQL authentication

Tags: mysql, mqtt, iot, mqtt-vernemq

I already have installed vernemq in my cloud server, everything seems running fine. But from any client, it is unable to connect the broker using username/password authentication. The authentication is based on MySQL, the Lua script is running fine. But strangely the authentication not working or something is wrong. I couldn't trace anything as nothing shows in Log. The only debug message I see is as follows:

> [debug] <0.227.0>@plumtree_broadcast:schedule_lazy_tick:720 0ms mailbox traversal, schedule next lazy broadcast in 10000ms, the min interval is 10000ms

OS : Ubuntu 18.04
MySQL Version : 5.7.29
VerneMQ Version : 1.10

Answer (score 0):

That debug log message is unrelated (it shows load information on the metadata exchange protocol).

Please make sure the password formats/hashing methods are compatible between VerneMQ and MySQL.